# How can i limit cron to one node

Tags: jelastic

When adding a node manually or via automatic horizontal scaling master node will be cloned. This means that also crontab will be cloned right?
How can i avoid, that a cron starts on two or more nodes simultaneously (which usually is not intended)?

Comment: How does your topology look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few possible ways:

- Your script can understand that it's not the master node, so it can remove itself from the cron or just do nothing. Each node has information about the master node in the layer/nodeGroup.

  ```
  env | grep MASTER
  MASTER_IP=172.25.2.1
  MASTER_HOST=node153580
  MASTER_ID=153580
  ```
- Disable cron via Cloud Scripting at [onAfterScaleOut](https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/events/#onafterscaleout). Here is an [example](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/cs-overview-example/blob/master/manifest.jps#L31) how to use this event.
- Deploy software templates as custom docker images (even if you use a certified Jelastic template). Such images are not cloned during horizontal scaling, they are created from scratch.

Comment: option 1 will be just fine for my case. will also look in option 2.
thank you for the complete answer :)

Comment: @csaggo I have the same case, but still don't understand how the option1 works, have you added some code logic to your app? can you please share what you've done?

Comment: @medBo in my case im running a php-script.
In the script i was able to get the above noted values with statement 
getenv('MASTER_HOST') 
for example. 
That you can compare to the current hostname 
so i compare getenv('MASTER_HOST') 
to 
$currentNode = trim(exec('hostname'));

(both values i cut at the first occurence of '-' because they are a little different afterwards, but i get nodeNNNN until first '-' in both.

Comment: @Ruslan can't get the ENV['MASTER_HOST'] with passenger in jelastic :( do you have any idea?

Comment: @csaggo thank you for the explanation it was really useful :)

Comment: @medBo your welcome! passenger is about ruby? i dont know ruby, but i assume there should be similar possibility to access env-vars.
if not it could be done in an sh-script outside the application, so make the check in  sh-script and let it start the actual app, when on master. i guess that would be a cleaner approach anyway as it keeps the actual app indepentend from hosting

Comment: @csaggo yes am using ruby on rails and generally to access these env variables you just have to do ENV['MASTER_HOST'] but somehow with passenger it's not possible to access it like that. I need it inside the app because am using a library that turn ruby code to cron job so it avoids me the hassle of writing cron syntax

Comment: @medBo I suggest to start your own question about this topic - it will be clearer to understand your exact problem and help to solve it.